# Drupal 7 Get image field path

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I would like to get the image path of a field. I'm in a node and I need the Url of image in order to put it as a background-image in inline css.
I can't find the solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

To get just the path of an image from it's URI:

```
file_create_url($node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
```

More information on file_create_url() can be found here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7

To get the path of an image created using an image style from it's URI use:

```
image_style_url($style, $node->field_image['und'][0]['uri']);
```

More information on image_style_url() can be found here: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_url/7

Comment: This doesn't take into account multilingual fields. See the answer by @Gergely below. Even if you think your site will "never" need to support translations, PLEASE don't do this. For more information, see http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Answer (score 21):

I am afraid, none of the solutions above are correct. They don't follow Drupal standards.

```
// field_video_image is the name of the image field

// using field_get_items() you can get the field values (respecting multilingual setup)
$field_video_image = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_video_image');

// after you have the values, you can get the image URL (you can use foreach here)
$image_url = file_create_url($field_video_image[0]['uri']);
```

More details here:
http://www.computerminds.co.uk/articles/rendering-drupal-7-fields-right-way

Comment: The above code is perfect. Generally most people wouldn't need to do this as described above, but if you want to write code that adheres to Drupal standards and won't break when things are changed or whatever, then it can't be emphasised how important this is.

Referring to items in code like so $object['und'][0]['element'] is extremely bad practice. Always use field_get_items or an equivalent.

Comment: This is an old question but as internet is filled with bad practices when it comes to getting field values in Drupal, this one should get more attention as it is the right way. As Jamie Hollern already wrote, you should NEVER use the ['und'][0] stuff that so many recommend.

Answer (score 5):

I sometime use this:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$img_url = $node->field_userimage['und'][0]['uri'];

<img src="<?php print image_style_url($style, $img_url) ?>" />
```

Comment: You can also use [theme_image_style()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--image--image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) instead of hard-coding the `<img>` tags

Comment: using the theme function would be much preferred: `theme('image_style', array('style_name' => 'name', 'path' => $node->field_userimage['und'][0]['uri'], 'alt' => 'Alt text'));`

Comment: Looks nice. I should start using those functions.

Comment: In a [Computed Field](https://drupal.org/project/computed_field), I could only access the _image field uri_ by this method.

Answer (score 2):

You also can use the [Image URL Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter) module. It allows to change the field format in order to get only the URL:

[image: Drupal field settings]

Bonus: it works with Views as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to get image style url:

```
$field = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_image');
$image_url = image_style_url('landingpage_slider', $field[0]['uri']);
```